# Can I execute only specific portion of nested if else in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic

This is not the actual code but it's what I want to do.

for loop is must but the nested if else loop inside should be executed according to the value of count_final which can be random between 1 to 3.

Like if the value of count_final is 3, all if...else loop should be considered. but if the value of count_final is 2, then only if...(1st)else if and else part only be executed. And if count_final=1 then only if and else part is executed (not any else-if).

Thought of putting another if...else within every if...else and checking count_final, but what if I'm not getting values of count2 and count3 when count_final=1.
Same, when count_final=2, I'm not getting the value of count3.

Ask in comment if you don't understand my question.

```
int count_final=Session["abc"];
//count_final=1;
//count_final=2;
//count_final=3;

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    if ((count1 <= count5) && (count1 <= count6))
    {
        Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
    else if (count2 <= count4 && count2 <= count6)
    {
        Label2.Text="Hello2";
    }
    else if (count3 <= count4 && count3 <= count5)
    {
        Label3.Text="Hello3";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a switch statement? what value does count1 have? where do you initialize it. Show me the actual code, because this is rubbish and unclear.

Comment: This seems a bit convoluted. I suspect that this might be made simpler by inspecting what it is you are actually trying to do here.

Comment: I agree with other comments, I imagine this is overkill of the solution you require, Maybe flesh out your question and explain countX etc

Comment: The question is very unclear.. are you trying to skip some conditions based on the value of count_final?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have collection of "conditions" where amount of executed conditions depend on value of `finalCount`.

```
var rules = new Func<string>[]
{
    () => (count1 <= count5 && count1 <= count6) ? "Hello1" : null,
    () => (count2 <= count4 && count2 <= count6) ? "Hello2" : null,
    () => (count3 <= count4 && count3 <= count5) ? "Hello3" : null
};

Label1.Text = rules.Take(finalCount)
                   .Select(rule => rule())
                   .Where(result => result != null)
                   .DefaultIfEmpty("Hello1")
                   .First();
```

Of course this solution is assuming that `finalCount` is always 1, 2 or 3.
`DefaultIfEmpty` is playing role of last `else` - will be used all conditions fails.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extending the conditions of your `else if` statements:

```
int count_final=Session["abc"];
//count_final=1;
//count_final=2;
//count_final=3;

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    if ((count1 <= count5) && (count1 <= count6))
    {
        Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
    else if (count_final >= 2 && count2 <= count4 && count2 <= count6)
    {
        Label2.Text="Hello2";
    }
    else if (count_final >= 3 && count3 <= count4 && count3 <= count5)
    {
        Label3.Text="Hello3";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
}
```

When `count_final == 1` this will not try to evaluate `count2`, `count3` or `count4` (which I understand is a requirement) because `&&` will not evaluate its right hand side when there is `false` on the left.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right.. which is a little unlikely

just add more criteria to your ifs!

```
   if ((count1 <= count5) && (count1 <= count6))  
    {
        if (count_final == 3 || count_final == 2) Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
    else if (count2 <= count4 && count2 <= count6)
    {
        if (count_final == 3) Label2.Text="Hello2";
    }
    else if (count3 <= count4 && count3 <= count5)
    {
        if (count_final == 3) Label3.Text="Hello3";
    }
    else
    {
        if (count_final == 3 || count_final == 1) Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
```

Remembering that from what I understood there will be loops in that can achieve nothing, eg, if `count_final == 2` and its not less or equal to `count5` or `count6`, nothing will happen, same as for `count_final == 1`, if it matches any of the first bits the last else wont happen.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? To use less if/else statements:

```
int count_final = Session["abc"];  // random between 1 and 3

for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    switch(count_final)
    {
        case 3:
            Label1.Text="Hello1";
        // no break; so all gets executed
        case 2:
            Label2.Text="Hello2";
        case 1:
            Label3.Text="Hello3";
        default: Label1.Text="Hello1";
    }
}
```